# How to use keyval option processing

Tags: key-value

I'm trying to make a command/environments with a view key value options similar to many other popular packages.

I found description on how to use key value but the examples don't work. Anyway can help to make a minimal key-value configured command `my`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{keyval}

\define@key{my}{foo}{Foo is #1\par}
\define@key{my}{bar}[99]{Bar is #1\par}

\newcommand{\KV@my@foo}[1]{Foo is #1}

\begin{document}

\my{foo=3,bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know the `keyval` package but if you want to use commands with an `@` in their names you at least must make `@` an letter before you use them, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/

Comment: Please note that nowadays there might be packages which are more robust and/or easier to use than `keyval`. IMHO, the three packages which should be considered nowadays to create new stuff are: `l3keys`/LaTeX-kernel key=value support (stable, built in), `expkv` (with `expkv-def` or `expkv-cs` -- disclaimer: I'm the author; stable, fast, in case of `expkv-cs` very easy for simple things), or `pgfkeys` (wide spread, versatile, flexible at use-time -- the last might be considered an advantage and a drawback).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

defining keys is usually in a package so guarded with `@` but you can use `\makeatletter` to write package code in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{my}{foo}{Foo is #1\par}
\define@key{my}{bar}[99]{Bar is #1\par}

\makeatother

\newcommand\my[1]{\setkeys{my}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\my{foo=3,bar}

\end{document}
```